# A task was canceled at ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, .net-5

I have two projects, one on **.NET 5** and the other on **.NET Core 3.1**.

Lately, I got email logging turned on, sending me emails whenever an error is thrown.

Every now and then, I get an email with the following error:

```
[Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

The problem is, the error never throws on the local development environment, and it probably corresponds to some network instability, **but I'm not sure where to start looking**.

For configuration across the app, I use the following initialization to allow injecting an AppSettings object to any class:

```cs
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
var appSettings = Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
var mqServerConnection = appSettings.MQServerConnection;

var identiyServerConfig = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(appSettings.IdentiyServerConnection));
services.Configure<IdentiyServerConnection>(identiyServerConfig);

var mqServerConfig = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(appSettings.MQServerConnection));
services.Configure<MQServerConnection>(mqServerConfig);
```

And then I'd be able to use AppSettings as:

```cs
public MyClassCtor(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
{
    var appSettings = options.Value;
}
```

Also, for authentication, I'm using an existing Identity Server, and here is how I integrate with it:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
         {
             config.Authority = appSettings.IdentiyServerConnection.Authority;
             config.Audience = appSettings.IdentiyServerConnection.Audience;
             config.RequireHttpsMetadata = appSettings.IdentiyServerConnection.RequireHttpsMetadata;
             config.BackchannelHttpHandler = WebHostEnvironment.IsProduction() ? new HttpClientHandler() : new HttpClientHandler
             {
                   ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
             };
             if (WebHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
             {
                  config.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
             }
          });
```

And then to use this form of authentication:

```cs
•••
app.UseAuthentication();
•••
```

Again, not sure where to start looking, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi @bfahm, you can add logger to your project to see where caused such issue.